# lwc-services is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: salesforce, lwc

I am trying to run a hellow world app in **LWC open source** and after "npx create-lwc-app my-app" when I cd in the dir and run "npm run watch" I get the below error.

```
E:\Development\LWC\workspace\dev>npm run watch

> dev@0.0.0 watch E:\Development\LWC\workspace\dev
> lwc-services watch

'lwc-services' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! dev@0.0.0 watch: `lwc-services watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the dev@0.0.0 watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-24T16_31_47_970Z-debug.log
```

Have tried to install "npm install --global --production windows-build-tools" again, trierd to manually install npm i lwc-services -g but it has an error 'rollup-plugin2.02 is dprecated update your dependency' but I donot know if that is the issue here , reistalled the nmp but still not working.

Comment: Were you able to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

You may try running 'npm run watch' after 'npm i' command.

The same issue has been asked [here](https://github.com/muenzpraeger/create-lwc-app/issues/70)

Answer (score 0):

I was instructed to do `npm install -g lwc-services`. There were several warnings, including "deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies."

That one seemed more serious than all the others, so I did `npm install chokidar`. That came in without any problems. Then I retried the previous command. I don't know if the Chokidar was such a big problem, but at least I was able to do the basic exercises and catch up with the rest of the class.